# "Embedded" attribute type should not be a map

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an @Embeddable type object:

```
@Embeddable
public class FileData {

    /* --- Members --- */

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

}
```

And I have another object which will hold it.

```
@Entity(name = "EmbeddingObject")
@Table(name = "embeddingObjcetTable")
public class EmbeddingObject {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "embeddingObjcetTable_files",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "embedding_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    private Set<File> files;


    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "embedding_id")
    @CollectionTable(name="embeddingObjcetTable_fileData",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "embedding_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    private Map<File, FileData> fileDataMapping;  <-- HERE
}
```

The error i'm getting is:

> “Embedded” attribute type should not be a map
>   The only embedded object is FileData.

Does anyone have a clue of what am I doing wrong?

I thought maybe it is just a warning, but the build actually fails.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide all the warnings and errors please.

Comment: Where is `File` class? embedded also?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. File object is a simple object. I've also added the error.

Comment: Define "simple object". Since you have an M-N RELATION to it above then it is an ENTITY, and you cannot EMBED an ENTITY and an EMBEDDABLE. But then you could POST `File` and we would know